# Firebase & Firestore - Grouping multiple apps into a project - How would auth work?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am looking to have a single Firebase Project with multiple unique apps. A user can have different accounts and identities in each app. I am using Firestore to hold basic identity information i.e preferred name etc.

My issue is around authentication of the user in each app. Is there a way in which a user can have different auth accounts in different apps?

i.e In app1, the user will have the email/password of user@abc.com with password123 and in app2, the same user will have the email/password of user@abc.com with password456?

Comment: I wrote how Firebase project share resources below. But it sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) now. If you want separate lists of users for each app, why do you want to host those apps in a single project? Why can't you host them in separate projects too?

Comment: It is solely financial consideration. There will be a quite a few apps, and individually, they won't bring in more than the Flame plan price. Considering what you said, use a project per app and find other ways to supplement the income.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic behind Firebase projects is that all apps within a project are essentially the same to the user. So it's quite normal to have an iOS and Android and a web app within a single project. It is even common to have different apps for different aspects of the project, or a lite and a pro version of the app.

What all of these scenarios have in common though, is that the resources of the project (including the list of users) is shared between all apps. What you're asking is to have separate lists of users for different apps. That is not what Firebase projects are meant for, so this isn't built in.

You can probably get this working by building your own custom identity provider for Firebase Authentication. But I'd still recommend against it, as you're likely to run into other limitations in the future, either as your project expands or as Firebase enforced the logic of having "one logical app" per project.

Answer (score 0):

[Control Access with Custom Claims and Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) documents how to do this.

> The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user
>   accounts. This provides the ability to implement various access
>   control strategies, including role-based access control, in Firebase
>   apps. These custom attributes can give users different levels of
>   access (roles), which are enforced in an application's security rules.
>
> User roles can be defined for the following common cases:
>
> - Giving a user administrative privileges to access data and resources.
> - Defining different groups that a user belongs to.
> - Providing multi-level access:
> - Differentiating paid/unpaid subscribers.
> - Differentiating moderators from regular users.
> - Teacher/student application, etc.
> - Add an additional identifier on a user. For example, a Firebase user could map to a different UID in another system.

Comment: I had a look at that article. That looks like a role based strategy.  If a user had to reset their password on a app, it would affect all other apps.